# A question on diagonalization of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to prove this:

> Let $V$ be a vector space. If $T\in L(V,V)$ is diagonalizable, then $V=\ker (T)\bigoplus \mathrm{Im}(T)$.

Well, if $T$ is a diagonalizable operator then there exists a basis $\beta=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ for which matrix of $T$ is diagonal. Let the eigenvalues be $\lambda_1,\dots\lambda_n$ so $$T(v_1)=\lambda_1v_1$$ $$\dots$$ $$T(v_n)=\lambda_nv_n$$ and let $v\in\ker (T)\cap \mathrm{Im}(T)$ be arbitrary. Then $T(v)=0$ and $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_iv_i$ so $0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}T(c_iv_i)$ so $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\lambda_iv_i=0$ so $c_i\lambda_i=0$, what can I conclude later?

Comment: Are you aware of the orthogonality of ker and Im? Maybe you should ask yourself wether if there is a $w \neq v$ such that $w \in \ker(T) \cap \mbox{Im}(T)$ or not.

Comment: @busman: You are confused. There is no inner product defined on $V$, and if there were, kernel and image would not need to be orthogonal. Here the question is just that (in this particular case) they must be complementary subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know this fact?

> $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $$V=E_{\lambda_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus E_{\lambda_k}$$ where $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ are the distinct eigenvalues of $T$ and each $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the eigenspace of $\lambda_i$.

Which eigenspace(s) in the above decomposition correspond to $\ker(T)$? Which eigenspace(s) above correspond to $\mbox{im}(T)$? Can you prove it?

**Edit**: Write
$$V=E_0 \oplus E_{\mu_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus E_{\mu_k}\tag{*}$$
where $E_0$ is the eigenspace for the eigenvalue 0 (so $E_0=\{0\}$ if $T$ has trivial kernel) and $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_k$ are the nonzero eigenvalues. Obviously $E_0 = \ker(T)$, so we have to show that $$\mbox{im}(T)=E_{\mu_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus E_{\mu_k}.$$ If $v \in \mbox{im}(T)$ then $v = T(v_0 + v_1 + \cdots + v_k)$ where $v_0 \in \ker(T)$ and $v_i \in E_{\mu_i}$ for $i>0$, by (*) above. So
$$v=Tv_1+\cdots+Tv_k=\mu_1v_1+\cdots+\mu_kv_k \in E_{\mu_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus E_{\mu_k}.$$ Conversely, if $v=v_1 + \cdots + v_k$ where $v_i \in E_{\mu_i}$ then
$$v = T(\mu_1^{-1}v_1+\cdots+\mu_k^{-1}v_k),$$
so $v\in\mbox{im}(T)$.

Comment: No, but if eigen vectors corresponding to $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ be $v_1,\dots v_n$, then I can say some of them(say $l<k$)generate the kerT

Comment: @Flute: I'm not sure what you are saying. My point was that $\ker(T)=E_0$, and $\mbox{im}(T)=\mbox{everything else}$. Now can you finish the proof?

Comment: what do you mean by $E_0$?

Comment: @Flute: The eigenspace for the eigenvalue 0.

Comment: A diagonalizable operator always has eigen value $0$? :-o

Comment: @Flute: No, but if it doesn't have 0 as an eigenvalue then its kernel is trivial.

Comment: Okay, that I did not know thank you.

Comment: could you solve it in detail? I am not able to get it.

Comment: @Flute: See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\ker T$ is nothing else than the eigenspace for the eigenvalue $0$ if such an eigenvalue exists. And if it doesn't exist, then $\ker T=\{0\}$ and $T$ is invertible.