# On a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, when does $V = \operatorname{Ker}(A) \bigoplus \operatorname{R}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This was a question given on a take-home exam that I have turned in. The deadline has passed, and I want to see if I gave a sufficient argument.

The question is posed as follows:

> Is it true that $V = \operatorname{Ker}(A) \bigoplus \operatorname{R}(A)$? Give a condition in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$ under which the claim holds.

Here, $V$ is assumed to be finite-dimensional, and $A$ is a square matrix that is the representation of some linear operator.

My solution is summarized as follows: If $0$ were not an eigenvalue of $A$, the claim holds, as the kernel of $A$ is zero-dimensional. The columns of $A$ then span $V$ by the Invertible Matrix Theorem, and any $v \in V$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Otherwise, suppose the kernel of $A$ is $p$-dimensional. Choose a basis for this kernel, and note that the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $0$ are precisely those vectors in the basis of $\operatorname{Ker}(A)$. Now construct a basis for each eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i}$. These build a collection of invariant subspaces under $A$ and form the range. So, consider specifically the basis of the range

$$ \operatorname{R}(A) = \operatorname{span} \{ v_{r_1, 1}, v_{r_1, 2}, \ldots , v_{r_{m_i}, m_i} \} $$

where each eigenspace has dimension $m_i$, and the sum of these dimensions is $n - p$ (by Rank-Nullity). Now consider the linear combination

$$ 0 = \sum_i c_{r_i, i} v_{r_i, i} + \sum_j d_{k_j, j} v_{k_j, j} $$

where $r_i$ indexes those vectors in the range and $k_j$ those in the kernel. Now apply $A$ on both sides. Since the second sum is in the kernel, its image is $0$. The first sum contains vectors that form a basis for the range, so each $c_{r_i, i} = 0$. Finally, the second sum forms a basis of the kernel, so each $c_{k_j, j} = 0$. We conclude $0$ has a unique representation, and $V = \operatorname{Ker}(A) \bigoplus \operatorname{R}(A)$.

While I did rush to get this in, I think the condition can be summarized as a TL;DR: Each eigenspace needs enough eigenvectors.

Are there flaws in my solution? Is there a condition nicer than "having enough eigenvectors?"

Comment: You have no warrant for asserting that the eigenspaces corresponding to the other eigenvalues span the range of $A$. That is only true if $A$ is diagonalizable. For example, the operator $A(x,y) = (y,0)$ has *no* eigenvectors different from $0$, and cannot be decomposed in the manner you suggest. This is also true for the operator $A(x,y,z)= (0,y+z,z)$, where the eigenspace corresponding to $1$, the only nonzero eigenvalue, is just $(0,y,0)$, which does not span the range of $A$.

Comment: Note that the second $A$ I list above does not satisfy your condition (the eigenspace of $1$ has geometric multiplicity $1$ but algebraic multiplicity $2$), but the condition you want holds, since the kernel is the space of all $(x,0,0)$, and the range is the space of all vectors of the form $(0,b,c)$. So if your condittion holds (diagonalizability) then the result holds, but this condition is not necessary.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This now makes sense to me. I left this question for the end because it was so open-ended. Can we loosen the diagonalizable condition, or is this "best?"

Comment: Using the fact that $\dim(W_1+W_2)+\dim(W_1\cap W_2) = \dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)$, it should be clear that the condition holds if and only if $R(A)\cap\mathrm{Ker}(A)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$. Show that the condition holds if and only if the nullity of $A$ equals the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does $V = \ker(f) \oplus \operatorname{im}(f)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247911/when-does-v-kerf-oplus-operatornameimf)

Answer (score -1):

Consider a Nilpotent matrix
$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &0 \\
0 & 0 &1  \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Then $ker(A)=\langle e_{1}\rangle$ ,while $R(A)=\langle e_{1};e_{2}\rangle$ So the decomposition mentionned is not true in general.
In fact  $V=Ker(A)\oplus R(A)$ if and only if $R(A)=R(A^{2})$ which is equivalent to $Ker(A)=Ker(A^{2})$ if and only if $Ker(A)\cap R(A)=\{0\}$ .suppose that we have the decomposition,then $A$ can be written in bloc matrix form as follows:
$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0\\
0 & C
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $B$ is the zero matrix $B:Ker(A)\to \ker(A)$ and $C:R(A)\to R(A)$ is invertible .The characterestic polynomial of $A$,denoted by $P_{A}$ equals $P_{B}\times P_{C}=x^{\text{dim} Ker(A)}\times P_{C}$ , where of course $P_{C}$ has non zero constant term ($P_{C}(0)\neq 0$)from this decomposition, u can see that a necessary condition for the existence of the decomposition is that  the algebraic and geometric multplicities of the eigenvalue 0 are equal.Conversely u can show that this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: ... which is not a condition in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, which is what the original problem asks for.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the remark,I edited my answer.